# Importing the latest MaxMind GeoLite2 database into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, geoip, maxmind

MaxMind is now offering a GeoLite2 DB [as described on their site](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/).

The trouble is that they no longer offer CSV download, only a binary MMDB binary database format.

I can't find anything online about how to unmangle the MMDB format and install it into my local MySQL database.

When I open the MMDB file in Notepad+, it's just a binary mess.

How can I use this MMDB file to populatte my local MySQL database?

Comment: i don't want to use their mmdb format.  i'd like to use it in a mysql database.  is this not possible anymore?  using composer, guzzle, and all the other plugins they require is way more complex than just getting the csv formats installed.

Comment: MaxMind will be releasing a CSV version of the database, although there isn't a specific timeline. The binary database with the GeoIP2 package will generally provide a better experience and installing it with composer is pretty simple. Alternatively, you could use the [MaxMind DB reader](https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader-php) directly. It does not have any external dependencies.

Comment: Any particular feature you need in GeoIP2? If not, you can stay with GeoIP1 or look at other option such as IP2Location LITE http://lite.ip2location.com

Comment: thanks.  the lite.ip2location.com databases are a good fit for now.  i'll wait for the csv version to come from maxmind.

Answer (score 6):

> MaxMind is now offering a GeoLite2 DB as described on their site.
>
> The trouble is that they no longer offer CSV download, only a binary
>   MMDB binary database format.

They do, now:

[Geolite2_city and Geolite2_country free CSV data bases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/)

Answer (score 1):

I made a utility [mmdb2csv](https://github.com/knoguchi/mmdb2csv) that can convert 4 mmdb types to CSV.  You can load the CSVs into MySQL and query from PHP.

- GeoIP2City.mmdb
- GeoIP2Connections.mmdb
- GeoIP2Country.mmdb
- GeoIP2ISP.mmdb

Answer (score 0):

Import the CSV file instead of MMDB file, it works with MySQL.